# May I please have the ability to flag posts just for my attention?

Tags: feature-request, flags

In short, can we have (or somebody tell me of an existing way) the ability to flag posts for personal review?

The reason for this is because I often see posts (mainly answers) that I feel need to be removed, but because I mainly check out the new questions I often avoid flagging a lot of them because I want to give the user a chance to improve the post. It would be nice if I could flag them for personal use, and then I could check my list for posts that are a few days old see if they still justify flagging to be removed.

Maybe "flagging" is the wrong term, I wouldn't want to have a feature that is specific for such a small number of users (or even just me). Perhaps something more generic like "memorable posts" or whatever. I don't really care what it's called, only that it would fit my needs.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: What I mean by "existing way" is an actual proper way to do it. Not a hack-around. If I wanted that I would create a Google doc and fill it with links. I think based on current replies that it is safe to say there is no decent feature for this so far

Comment: You can favour the questions and revist them later.

Comment: If you haven't already used the favorites feature for something else, then that is what you could use, but it's not specific to an answer.

Comment: You can also comment on them and mention what improvements can be made. The comments are listed in your user profile under `activity` and you can use these to find the questions again.

Comment: Favourites is not ideal. And commenting is not good if I am an active commenter and comment on many different things (which I do)

Comment: Commenting is currently the best way to do this that I have found. You do have to look through your comments as you've said yeah but once you get used to looking for your comments requesting improvement, this process becomes much quicker. I tend to phrase my comments in the same way for similar issues so can pick them out quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can click the star icon next to the question to add it to your favorites. Questions that you have starred will then appear on your "favorites" tab on your profile - questions that have recent changes will be highlighted in that list. If you visit a question to review it by clicking on the link from your list of favorites, you can review it, remove the star, and clear it from your list.

It's a slightly different use of stars from what the feature was intended for, but it should work for your purposes.

Comment: What were they intended for?  I tend to think of the feature as "for whatever you need to keep track of."

Comment: Yeah, I see what you are saying, but I tend to use the favourites feature for my favourite questions. Which are ones I find super useful, and those which I would be interested in knowing the answer (but it has yet to be answered)

Comment: @djechlin: They were intended as favorites... i.e. questions you really like. You would mark a question as a favorite simply because you like it, and not necessarily because you want to track its activity.

Comment: @djechlin What BoltClock said :)

Comment: I don't think this is what the user meant. He/she said "posts": " I want to give the user a chance to improve the post. It would be nice if I could flag them for personal use, and then I could check my list for posts that are a few days old see if they still justify flagging to be removed."

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe a feature like this currently exists, but perhaps the current "favourite" feature could be expanded so that the star icon appears underneath answer votes as well as question votes.

Furthermore this feature could then display a modal box which allows the user to select an optional category/categories to put the post under.

This would then allow users to favourite any post they wish, and ensure they can use the favourite feature for different intentions.

I think this feature should be renamed to something else as "favourite" would suggest the posts have only been marked because you *like* them, not that you are marking them to review later for moderation purposes etc.

In which case I would suggest "Favourites" could be a default category.

Comment: This would actually be an ideal solution in my opinion. It is generic enough to be suitable for all, but is also flexible enough to suit many specific use cases too.